# ajax with html issue

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to get the html of a website to check it for links,
I use the following ajax code to get the html of a remote website:

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'get',
  url : 'proxy.php',
  dataType : 'html',
  success : function(data){
    alert('success');
  },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert('error');
  }
});
```

proxy.php is the proxy I use to get the data because it is not on my server :

```
<?php
// Set your return content type
header('Content-type: application/html');

// Website url to open
$daurl = 'http://example.com';
// Get that website's content
$handle = fopen($daurl, "r");

// If there is something, read and return
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

the code always alert the error and I can not understand is everything is OK because I am not expert with ajax so I want anybody that could check that for me? is it wrong ajax datatype? is it wrong header in proxy file please???

Comment: In your error function try alerting textStatus or errorThrown rather than a string saying error and tell us what the error is.

Comment: the textStatus alert error but the errorThrown alert Not found

Comment: have you checked the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

You are serving the html file retrieved with `proxy.php` with a wrong `Content-type`.

The right  content-type should be `text/html` instead of `application/html`.

If you browse to your `proxy.php` file you would see that you are not getting any content and that your browser tries to download the page.

After the changing to the right content-type, if you browse to `proxy.php` you would see the contents in your browser.

So, this is the line you've to change:

```
<?php
// Set your return content type
header('Content-type: text/html');
```